# Accordion issue in Table - jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, accordion

i am binding the data dynamically.

but Accordion is not working properly.

**JSFiddle link**

http://jsfiddle.net/aff4vL5g/360/

**please note:** I cant change the HTML structure

**Current table** 
[image]

**Out put i needed**

first accordion on click should dispaly child elements
[image]

Second accordion on click should dispaly child elements
[image]

**where i am doing wrong??**

HTML

```
    <table>
    /* first parent*/ 
             <tr>
              <td>
                 <a href="#">
                    <div id="accordion"></div>
                 </a>
              </td>
              <td><a href="#">Profit</a></td>
              <td>35%</td>
              <td>22%</td>

           </tr>
    /* child1*/ 
           <tr class="parentTR">
              <td></td>
              <td>
                 <a href="#" >
                    <div id="accordion"></div>
                    Business - 1
                 </a>
              </td>
              <td>35%</td>
              <td>22%</td>

           </tr>
    /* child2*/ 
           <tr class="parentTR">
              <td></td>
              <td>
                 <a href="#">
                    <div id="accordion"></div>
                    Business - 2
                 </a>
              </td>
              <td>38%</td>
              <td>28%</td>
           </tr>
/* second parent*/ 
             <tr>
              <td>
                 <a href="#">
                    <div id="accordion"></div>
                 </a>
              </td>
              <td><a href="#">Loss</a></td>
              <td>15%</td>
              <td>12%</td>

           </tr>
    /* child1*/ 
           <tr class="parentTR">
              <td></td>
              <td>
                 <a href="#" >
                    <div id="accordion"></div>
                    Business - 1
                 </a>
              </td>
              <td>35%</td>
              <td>22%</td>

           </tr>
    /* child2*/ 
           <tr class="parentTR">
              <td></td>
              <td>
                 <a href="#">
                    <div id="accordion"></div>
                    Business - 2
                 </a>
              </td>
              <td>38%</td>
              <td>28%</td>
           </tr>
        </table>
```

Jquery

```
$(function () {
    //  Accordion Panels
    $(".parentTR").hide();
    $("a .accordion ").click(function () {
        $(this).next(".parentTR").slideToggle("slow").siblings(".parentTR:visible").slideUp("slow");
        $(this).toggleClass("active");
        $(this).siblings(".accordion").removeClass("active");
    });
});
```

Any Help is Appreciated

Thanks

Comment: You are saying accordion as class in js while the HTML has id #accordion

Comment: @anpsmn sorry my mistake , it is ID. i will update the Fiddle now

Comment: Ids should be unique. Use as class.

Comment: @anpsmn even if i use class also the accordions are not working http://jsfiddle.net/aff4vL5g/359/

Comment: You have spelled accordion differently in js and html. Also this.next won't work as accordion doesn't have a sibling. You need to go to it's parent tr and then say next.

Comment: @anpsmn  i have updated the fiddle with changed typo

Comment: @anpsmn  sorry i dont know how to make it parent?? can you please help me here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to go to the parent tr and then access the sibling with .next()

```
$(this).closest('tr')
     .next(".parentTR").slideToggle("slow")
     .siblings(".parentTR:visible").slideUp("slow");
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aff4vL5g/361/)

Comment: i will test it and get back to you

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, i have used class.

now i am getting the accordion. thanks Once again

Answer (score 1):

I try with this solution [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8k8xqkqn/6/)

HTML :

```
     <table>
     <tr childTRClass="A1">
      <td>
         <a href="#">
            <div class="accordion"></div>
         </a>
      </td>
      <td><a href="#">Profit</a></td>
      <td>35%</td>
      <td>22%</td>
   </tr>

   <tr class="childTR A1">
      <td></td>
      <td>
         <a href="#" >
            <div class="accordion"></div>
            Business - 1
         </a>
      </td>
      <td>35%</td>
      <td>22%</td>
   </tr>
   <tr class="childTR A1">
      <td></td>
      <td>
         <a href="#">
            <div class="accordion"></div>
            Business - 2
         </a>
      </td>
      <td>38%</td>
      <td>28%</td>
   </tr>

     <tr childTRClass="A2">
      <td>
         <a href="#">
            <div class="accordion"></div>
         </a>
      </td>
      <td><a href="#">Loss</a></td>
      <td>15%</td>
      <td>12%</td>
   </tr>

   <tr class="childTR A2">
      <td></td>
      <td>
         <a href="#" >
            <div class="accordion"></div>
            Business - 1
         </a>
      </td>
      <td>35%</td>
      <td>22%</td>
   </tr>
   <tr class="childTR A2">
      <td></td>
      <td>
         <a href="#">
            <div class="accordion"></div>
            Business - 2
         </a>
      </td>
      <td>38%</td>
      <td>28%</td>
   </tr>

</table>
```

JQuery:

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
  $(".childTR").hide();
    $('a .accordion').click(function() {
        var openTRClass = $(this).closest('tr').attr('childTRClass');
               $(".childTR:visible").slideUp("slow");
       $("."+ openTRClass).slideToggle("slow")
               if($('.active').length > 0)
        {
            $('.active').removeClass("active");
        }

        $(this).toggleClass("active");        
    });
});
```

Comment: can please provide me the link

Comment: sorry i am not using jQuery UI 1.9.2, is there any solution without using it

Comment: using jquey 1.8.3  but not using jquery UI

Comment: I change JSFiddle url, see it

Answer (score 1):

First need to go to main parent.

```js
$(function () {
    $(".parentTR").hide();
    
    $("a .accordion ").click(function () {
        $(".parentTR").hide();
        $(this).closest('.main').nextUntil(".main").slideToggle("slow");
       
        $(this).toggleClass("active");
        $(this).siblings(".accordion").removeClass("active");
    });
});
```

Here's the [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aff4vL5g/368/).