# jQuery Accordion function to get all child rows by clicking a row

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I am new to jQuery, I have been googling for hours to find some good jQuery accordion example that I can use. I have found some like [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28849564/accordion-issue-in-table-jquery)

But problem with this, it only displays one child row only. Is there any way that if I click a row I can get all child rows something like bootstrap does by using data-target attribute.

here is the example table.

```
   <table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Package ID</th>
            <th>Quantity</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr class="accordion-toggle" data-target=".packageDetails1">
            <td>123456</td>
            <td>3</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="accordion packageDetails1">
                <td>Revealed item 1</td>
                <td>Revealed item 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="accordion packageDetails1">
                <td>Revealed item 3</td>
                <td>Revealed item 4</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="accordion-toggle" data-target=".packageDetails2">
            <td>654321</td>
            <td>3</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="accordion packageDetails2">
                <td>Revealed item 5</td>
                <td>Revealed item 6</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="accordion packageDetails2">
                <td>Revealed item 7</td>
                <td>Revealed item 8</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

here is the function that I tried.

```
$(function () {
    $("accordion-toggle ").click(function () {
        $(this).next(".accordion").slideToggle("slow").siblings(".accordion:visible").slideUp("slow");
        $(this).toggleClass("active");
        $(this).siblings(".accordion-toggle").removeClass("active");
    });
});
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: The code in the question is entirely different from the jsFiddle? Also, please include all relevant code within the question so that it's useful for future visitors

Comment: is it good now ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the js fiddle provided, If you give the 'tr' that contains the '.accordion' link a class (used '.pnt' here), then using closest('tr') will target the parent 'tr' of the one you are clicking and then nextUntil(".pnt") will target the subsequent rows up to '.pnt'.

```
$(this).closest("tr").nextUntil(".pnt").slideToggle("slow");
    $(this).toggleClass("active");
    $(this).siblings(".accordion").removeClass("active");
});
```

Comment: Thanks Johnny. that's great :)